# Is time a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to derive the equation for the mean value of a function, the standard formula is given by: 
$$\frac{1}{T} \int^T_0{g(t)dt}$$
To do this I have used the law of the unconscious statistian given by:
$$E(g(\tau))= \int^T_0{g(t)f(t)}dt$$
where $f(t)$ is the pdf of the random variable $\tau$. In the case of nuclear decay $\tau$ would simply be the mean life time. But in this I would need $\tau$ to be time itself, is this allowed? can I consider time to be a continuous random variable with a uniform distribution)?

If the answer is no can I do it be letting $A$ be a random variable with a uniform distribution between $t=0$ and $t=T$  and then use:
$$E(g(A))= \int^T_0{g(t)f(t)}dt$$
If I have made a mistake or you need any clarification just say, thanks.

Comment: Physicists have been making mathematicians mad for a long time by breaking the rules. The Dirac δ is an example. The question for you to answer is whether treating time this way gives you a useful answer.

Comment: @PaulMagnussen Yes it does give me a useful answer, but I would prefer not to break the 'rules' (by the way I am a physicist) and want to do it in a way that is mathematically correct

Comment: Where does $\tau$ figure in your integral?